# Binary cross entropy Vs categorical cross entropy with 2 classes

Tags: python, pytorch, cross-entropy

When considering the problem of classifying an input to one of 2 classes, 99% of the examples I saw used a NN with a single output and sigmoid as their activation followed by a binary cross-entropy loss.  Another option that I thought of is having the last layer produce 2 outputs and use a categorical cross-entropy with C=2 classes, but I never saw it in any example.
Is there any reason for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `softmax` on top of the two output network you get an output that is *mathematically* equivalent to using a single output with `sigmoid` on top.
Do the math and you'll see.

In practice, from my experience, if you look at the raw "logits" of the two outputs net (before `softmax`) you'll see that one is exactly the negative of the other. This is a result of the gradients pulling *exactly* in the opposite direction each neuron.

Therefore, since both approaches are equivalent, the single output configuration has less parameters and requires less computations, thus it is more advantageous to use a single output with a sigmoid ob top.