# Semantic Segmentation — Usage of Categorical Cross-Entropy in spite of Binary Cross-Entropy for Binary Image Segmentation

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, cross-entropy, semantic-segmentation

I have read both on SO and on CValidated and still feel I do not completely understand the following matter.

If I have a binary segmentation (consider a medical problem, where you have healthy and damaged tissue), which loss is better to use, BCE or CCE?

Some have stated that(and I perfectly understand) that CCE is more computationally expensive than BCE for binary classification and that there is no reason for using CCE. While I understand the justification, I have not found a study which clearly compares the final output/results compared side by side (Acc/Dice/Jaccard metrics on validation/test datasets with BCE vs CCE).

Are there clear cases in which BCE outperforms CCE or vice-versa for binary segmentation?

Comment: Categorical cross-entropy for two classes is same to binary cross-entropy.

Comment: After some digging, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726064/binary-cross-entropy-vs-categorical-cross-entropy-with-2-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided at the following link [Binary cross entropy Vs categorical cross entropy with 2 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726064/binary-cross-entropy-vs-categorical-cross-entropy-with-2-classes).

It is stated that from a mathematical viewpoint(result, not computational overhead), softmax on two classes is exactly the same like in case of BCE, the same answer as @f4f.

Comment: To measure if there is any computational overhead you shall test your setup, obviously its dependent on used framework. But I think that state of the art frameworks will perform with same efficiency for both cases.

Comment: Thank you for the response, sensible observation.

Comment: You are welcome.